# Calculate or Update Average without iteration over time

Tags: algorithm

Consider a small monitoring device which displays temperature average every 10 seconds.

```
timestamp               value
20190304000000           62.7
20190304000010           62.5
20190304000020           62.8 
.... 
....
```

how to calculate and update average without increasing memory footprint. that is, whole data storage (persistent or memory) in not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to other answers, you might want to use IIR filter to get [Exponential moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average): `filter that applies weighting factors which decrease exponentially`, so last values have more impact than older ones

```
newAverage = OldAverage * (1-alpha) + NewValue * alpha
```

where `alpha` is small value like 0.1 that has relation to decreasing time/constant

Comment: alpha = 2/(N+1), where N is count?

Comment: No, alpha is constant (choosed for desired weight decreasing rate) and is not related to overall count.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a total sum, and a count of the number of temperatures recorded. Then divide the sum by the count every time you report the answer, to avoid compounding floating point errors.

```py
from itertools import count

temperature_sum = 0
for temperature_count in count(1):
    temperature_sum += read_from_sensor()
    print("Average: {}".format(temperature_sum / temperature_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

we will need two variables

```
int count;
float average;

void main() {
   do while(true) {
      float temperature = ReadFromSensor(); //not included
      average = ((average*count) + temperature)/ ++count;
      cout << "average: " << average << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is bad form, and will cause floating point errors to compound as the count increases.